# Google Hangouts on iPhone - how to have two accounts

Tags: iphone, google

Can I receive notifications from 2 Google Talk/ Hangouts accounts, by installing only one app?
Does the official Google Hangouts app support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to add that this is done by clicking on your profile picture and touching the +Manage Accounts item that then appears below your profile picture.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Hangout's settings you can add new accounts.